# Visual studio code cmd error: Cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: powershell, command-line, visual-studio-code

Inside of visual studio code, I'm trying to execute a script.bat from the command line, but I'm getting the following error:

> File C:\Theses_Repo\train-cnn\environment\Scripts\activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.

After reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6) I tried to run the visual studio code in administrator mode, thinking that the problem was a matter of privileges. But the error is throwing anyway.

Comment: 1. Press the windows-button on your keyboard.

2. Type ‘PowerShell’

3. Right-click Windows PowerShell

4. Click Run as Administrator

5. Run the following command and confirm with ‘Y’

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine


Referred to link https://www.roelpeters.be/solved-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system-in-powershell/

Answer (score 319, accepted):

**Update August 2021**

It seems that `terminal.integrated.shellArgs` is deprecated. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67420296/5148197) answer shows how to do it in new versions.

**Original Answer**

I found out [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2559#issuecomment-478381840) that you can add to your [visual studio code settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) the following and the problem will vanish:
For visual studio code settings, go to File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Scroll down and find "Edit in settings.json". *Do not forget to restart the visual studio code*

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

The reason is that, in build command line integrations like visual studio code, you need to set the command line policies by your self. By setting the above configurations, the visual studio code will do that for you.

*(read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6#bypass) to understand better the command line policies)*

Comment: Thanks a million. This did the trick for me (after 1h of research) and saved me another headache.

Comment: OK, my mistake. I also had to set Powershell as my default terminal.

Comment: Thank you sir! After you add this in settings.json , you should reload or reopen vscode, a notification will ask you if you want to grant access for execution policy.

Comment: Where in the VSCode settings do you add this?

Comment: @Andy You have in the link associated with the phrase "visual studio code settings "

Comment: @Andy, Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Scroll down and find "Edit in settings.json"

Comment: thank you very much. Now i got more time to core developping.

Comment: For me I searched for `terminal.integrated.shellArgs` as @Barani mentioned.

Comment: Go to the @null comment (three posts below) and you can see that you just have to change from Powershell to CMD as default command prompt. That's all!

Comment: Or just hit ctrl + shift + p and type "Open settings.json". You will see the option. Just click it and it will open your settings.json

Comment: there are one million of "Edit in settings.json". Javed's answer worked for me.

Comment: the shellArgs is deprecated in the new versions as it answered below https://stackoverflow.com/a/67420296/2514158  @MoishyS

Comment: Why suggest the "Bypass" policy by default? Wouldn't "RemoteSigned" be safer?

Comment: Great. This answer helped me to get rid of this exact problem occurred to me. 
Just to describe the steps little more..

After you go to the **File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Scroll down and find "Edit in settings.json" path**, It will open up **settings.json file**. and there, I added this code like this
`{
    
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"],
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "json.schemas": [

    ]
}`

Comment: Related answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023796/visual-studio-code-unsigned-powershell-scripts

Answer (score 238):

the issue is that PowerShell by default restricts running scripts unless we change the [execution policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1#bypass).

we can change the execution policies by adding `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` args. in vscode you will have to create a [Terminal Profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles) with these args by adding below in User Settings or in Workspace Settings (ctrl + shift + p and type "settings json")

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  "PowerShell": {
    "source": "PowerShell",
    "icon": "terminal-powershell",
    "args": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
  }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
```

Need to restart VS Code and the Terminal.

Note: `terminal.integrated.shellArgs` settings have been [deprecated](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56#_terminal).

Comment: Note: defaultProfile is known not to work on the initial restored terminal [#123188](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123188) - when you open the terminal from the + button it should work.
hopefully will get fixed soon.

Comment: As of May 2021 this is the correct solution. The old method of setting terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows no longer works.

Comment: This worked perfectly. The previous answers are depreciated in VS Code. Thank you!

Comment: Had to restart the powershell within vscode to make this work. Thanks.

Comment: This works, just needed to restart VS Code and the Terminal afterwards

Comment: VSCode might give you three options of settings.json: workspace settings, default settings, and just settings. It didn't work for me unless I chose the last option: Open Workspace Settings.

Comment: works perfectly. I also had to start a new powershell inside VSCODe with + button.

Comment: thank you so much. I was very upset after installing typescript and got this error

Comment: This solution kind of worked for me.   I was unable to change the settings.json file as it was read-only when doing it this way.   I had to combine with a "flavor" of Abdu's answer.   I had to use File->Preferences->Settings and select "Edit in settings.json" in order to modify the file.   I searched for "profiles" instead of "automation" though....not sure what the automation settings are, but they didn't work for me.

Comment: This solution works: I edited the "User" settings.json (not default, not workspace). Restarting VS Code only didn't pick up the changes. I did what @Ani said and deleted my PowerShell terminal window (use the "Kill terminal" trashcan icon on the right side of the terminal area) then "+" create a new instance. Then my settings were picked up and tsc command worked.

Comment: If you're adding it to a new (empty) settings.json file, such as a workspace settings, the settings example shown must be enclosed in { }.

Comment: why are you giving a solution which evolve in another problem? theres no way you can edit the default cfg file, neither user cfg file works

Answer (score 165):

The simplest way to deal with this problem from Visual Studio Code is to change from powerShell to cmd (assuming there's no reason for using powershell in your case). To do so, follow these few steps:

1. Terminal -> New Terminal
2. In right lower corner select "Select Default Shell" option

[image]

3. Select "Command prompt"

[image]

I have not found such solution among current answers.

Comment: This simple solution work great for me, I try the other solutions with no success.

Comment: Now this is updated as "Select default profile"

Answer (score 109):

**UPDATE**

ShellArgs is deprecated. Now, as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67420296/11457981) answer you can use ***profiles*** to bypass execution policies.

---

For more simplicity, I want to add the vs code settings path in addition to Ricardo's answer. you can get it like this:

File -> Preferences -> Settings and in the search bar write "automation".

After that, by looking your operating system enter "edit in settings.json".

Finally, add the following b/n the braces:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

[image]

Comment: Might be a silly question but what's b/n here?

Comment: It is a short hand for between.

Answer (score 70):

Face the same issue and this works for me.
open PowerShell as Administrator and paste this.

```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Comment: More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6

Comment: this worked fine for me other suggestions (apart from using the cmd instead of powershell) did not work

Answer (score 49):

1. Press the windows-button on your keyboard
2. Type 'PowerShell'
3. Right-click Windows PowerShell
4. Click Run as Administrator
5. Run the following command and confirm with ‘Y’

   `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine`

for more information: https://www.roelpeters.be/solved-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system-in-powershell/

Hope this would resolve the issue

Comment: thanks a lot , I tried all solutions , but only this one help me

Answer (score 23):

1. Open VS code
2. File -> Prefrences -> settings
3. in the Search bar -> Search for "terminal.integrated.shellArgs"
4. Click on the "Edit in setting.json" for Terminal>integrated>ShellArgs > windows [whatever you OS, select the respective settings]
5. At the top of the json file add this :

   **terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]**

   For example after adding your json might look like:

> ```
> {
>     "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"],
>     "git.autofetch": true,
>     "peacock.favoriteColors": [
>         {
>             "name": "Angular Red",
>             "value": "#b52e31"
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "Auth0 Orange",
>             "value": "#eb5424"
>         },
> ```

6. restart the VS code and try the command again (in my case i was trying ng serve)

**Note: terminal.integrated.shellArgs settings have been deprecated.**

Answer (score 20):

Run the below command then the issue will be resolved.

`set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`
( I tried only in windows )

Comment: Just some more additional information on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1)

Answer (score 15):

I have faced the same problem due to security reasons on Windows 10.
I managed to fix it by running the following command in PowerShell:

```bsh
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Answer (score 12):

1. Open VS code
2. Go to File -> Prefrences -> settings
3. in the Search bar -> Search for "terminal.integrated.defaultprofile.windows"
4. Click on the "Edit in setting.json" for Terminal > integrated > Default Profile: Windows [whatever you OS, select the respective settings].

At the top of the JSON file add this :

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "args": [
            "-ExecutionPolicy",
            "Bypass"
        ]
    }
},
```

Note: The following settings line is deprecated:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

Comment: Thank you. And it needs to restart the VS code.

Answer (score 10):

I opened VS Code as Administrator and ran this command in the terminal:

```bsh
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

It allowed me to run the scripts without an errors.

Comment: This might work but sounds like bad practice from a security standpoint.

Answer (score 7):

For security reasons, in case you share the computer with other users, use:
PowerShell:

> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted

No need for Admin privileges.

Comment: After entering the above command it works

Answer (score 5):

Steps to resolve the issue,

1. Open PowerShell in your Computer (This will change the PowerShell execution policy on your Windows Computer)
2. Run ( To get-ExecutionPolicy for your Machine )

> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

3. Run

> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to explicitly run this on PowerShell, then you may want to try running it in the command prompt.

Just type `cmd` and press enter. Doing so will open the command prompt in the current terminal window. It will behave same as a normal command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

For Win10 users

1. In Visual Studio Code: `File -> Preferences -> Settings`
2. Type in the search: `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows`
3. Click on the `Edit in setting.json`
4. Add this:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  "PowerShell": {
    "path" : [
      "${env:windir}\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
    ],
    "source": "PowerShell",
    "icon": "terminal-powershell",
    "args": [
      "-NoLogo",
      "-ExecutionPolicy",
      "ByPass"]
  }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
```

5. Save and restart Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 3):

The location of tag is changed, Steps:

1. Do Ctrl+Shift+P and type 'settings' and then choose 'Preferences: Open settings (JSON)':
   [image: Locating settings]
2. Then add "args": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"] inside "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows"."PowerShell" in settings.json :
   [image: SettingsJSON]
3. Restart VS code.

There can be different steps if anything changed with VS code updates in future.

Comment: why do we have shit tools like vscode , just use pycharm , its way better

Comment: I think people working on windows finds it better, WebStorm is also good but its paid.

Comment: i use windows , i generally use both of them (to keep me updated) , my GitHub desktop is connected to vscode for final reviews/comments but my development env. is pycharm , and pycharm is so much better.

Answer (score 2):

Added this line in settings.json

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell"
```

For me used following command in VS powershell and it starts working

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Answer (score 1):

Run VS-Code as ADMIN.

This fixed my issue on my home PC with running ng new my-App which had produced this error when I first opened VS-Code from the installation process.

Comment: This fixed the issue for one run, but then it came back.  The solution above worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few minutes ago:
I did this and it worked for me

You need to edit your visual studio settings.
Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Scroll down and find "Edit in settings.json". Past these codes below, save, and restart the visual studio code.

```
   {
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell",
            "args": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
        }
    },
    
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
    "files.associations": {
        "*.html": "html"
    },
}
```

Comment: where should you put this?

Comment: Hi @JovaneMullings
I've edited my answer with clear path of where you need to paste this. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Adding this error message just to find this topic easily in the future:

```
    ng : File C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
    https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
    At line:1 char:1
    + ng help
    + ~~
        + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually require the default terminal be windows Powershell, I would suggest simply changing the type of terminal. It's very easy to do:
On the right top part of the shell click on the small down-facing arrow next to the plus sign. Then choose which terminal you would like to use (I like good old CMD) and you can even pick a default for the next time you open a new treminal.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a VSCode specific issue, it is a OS one. ***There are different levels for machine, user, process that allow PowerShell Scripts to run and it must be enabled.***

If this is your machine just change the execution policy to RemoteSigned or unrestricted so that is applies to your entire system. If you just want to use it in VSCode, the change your settings file or change you shortcut to include the execution policy you want to use. The Recommendation is RemoteSigned. Meaning all local code will run, but any remote scripts must be signed.

If this is a corporate machine, that has the Execution set to Restricted, then no code will run until that setting is changed. You can still run code by selecting it all in the VSCode editor and hitting F8. Now, if they have enforced this policy, then you need to talk to the IT time to get them to change it for you.

All of this is detailed in the PowerShell Help files.

```
Get-Command -Name '*executionpolicy*' | ft -AutoSize

CommandType Name                Version Source                       
----------- ----                ------- ------                       
Cmdlet      Get-ExecutionPolicy 3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Security
Cmdlet      Set-ExecutionPolicy 3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Security


# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Get-ExecutionPolicy).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-ExecutionPolicy -Full
Get-help -Name Get-ExecutionPolicy -Online
Get-help -Name Get-ExecutionPolicy -Examples

    Get-ExecutionPolicy
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
    Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

(Get-Command -Name Set-ExecutionPolicy).Parameters
Set-help -Name Set-ExecutionPolicy -Full
Set-help -Name Set-ExecutionPolicy -Online
Set-help -Name Set-ExecutionPolicy -Examples

    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Restricted
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName "Server01" -ScriptBlock {Get-ExecutionPolicy} | Set-ExecutionPolicy -Force
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy AllSigned -Force
    Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Undefined
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy AllSigned
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Note, if your org is controlling this, the again, talk to them [before trying to bypass the policy](https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy/), because if they did this, this also means they are monitoring it, and if you do this that will know. I have seen things like this engender RPE's. (Resume Producing Events)

Answer (score 0):

I Have this error in my visual studio 2019 (Version 16.8.4).
Finally I found solution which is:
EnableScripts (Make from PowerShell os windows (from Registry Editor of windows 10)

Brows the PowerShell as bellow and make 0 => 1 and that is it.

[image: Registry Editor]

[image: Registry Editor]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After tearing my hair out this is what I ended up doing. Instead of using CMD or PowerShell I switched over to BASH.
In the settings.json:

```
//"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
// "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",   
        "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
```

The CMD and Powershell here are commented out in case you want to go back to one of those.
To get to settings.json:

```
> File -> Preferences -> Settings -> in search type : "settings.json" ->
> Under [JSON] click "Edit in settings.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while trying to use pnpm. I just changed to GitBash instead of PowerShell for vs-code terminal, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

since we are in 2022, and vdcode has changed the way to fix this issue in setting.json just open the terminal and run

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear where should I add it (`"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]`).

I have a code like this in the settings.json file

```
{
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\Hansamal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python.exe",
"workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
},
"notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
    "default": "right",
    "jupyter-notebook": "left"
},
"json.schemas": [

]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

#### Update Powershell Execution Policy.

Setting a global unrestricted execution policy will run any script. But also shows a warning from windows.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Instead allow the script that is being run. You can find the full path of the script from the error.

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\webpack.ps1
```

Here I have provided access to webpack for running.