# tsc.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: typescript, powershell

On PowerShell, I got the error message when executing `tsc`. This never happened before.

I am not sure should I mingle with the PowerShell security settings to rectify this such as based on this one: [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

### Update

This is a new intended feature by npm to use ps1 scripts. A question has been raised in their repo: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/470

Comment: You don't have much choice. The script execution policy needs to be set to allow running of .ps1 scripts on a Windows system.
You can avoid by running within Powershell ISE or similar but otherwise the system policy will dictate.

Comment: I realised the older version of npm will not include the ps1 file, not sure why they started doing now.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with setting the PowerShell script execution policy to at least "RemoteSigned".

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers alright then

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You can run this in PowerShell command. Be sure to run it as administrator:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Comment: can you give some more details to what this does? and how safe it is?

Comment: It is super important to run the PowerShell as Administrator

Comment: Please provide details on what it is and what it does. I see so many upvotes on an answer with no explanation. Please don't make SO a site where people come for hacks instead of learning.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7

Comment: Very good solution, solved my problem with typescript

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7

Comment: Can add `-Scope CurrentUser` to avoid having to log in as admin

Comment: or you can use command prompt terminal in vscode instead of the powershell (if you have the option)

Comment: The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170 .

Comment: i too don't trust this command, someone explain it please ??

Comment: [PowerShell's execution policy is a safety feature, not a security feature](https://westmesatech.com/?p=33).

Answer (score 132):

Use `tsc.cmd` instead of `tsc`. For example:

```
tsc.cmd -v
tsc.cmd --init
```

Comment: Just for clarification: `tsc` is a bash script - `tsc.cmd` is a Windows version of the script.

Answer (score 32):

Open Command_form :  **windows + R**

Type : **Powershell**

Then type :

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

And select option : **A**

Comment: Please try to run the windows power shell in admin mode And try this command, and this solution solved the same problem for me.

Answer (score 21):

this problem happend with me
the solution is
tsc.cmd [filename.ts]

it will work

Comment: This seems a bit unclear - question was regarding a powershell script. You're proposing to use tsc.cmd to run a typescript file - maybe expand a bit, and tell where to get the ts file and how i relates to tsc.ps1

Comment: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/470#issuecomment-586845035 npm in Windows will still install a cmd version

Comment: I don't know why it's downvoted, but I found this useful, rather than changing execution policy in PowerShell.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.    The fix is on the npm developer side.  They should name their ps script differently from the compiled executable.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Visual Studio Code you can use `tsc.cmd` instead of `tsc`. It worked fine for me.

Comment: this does it for me

Answer (score 9):

Use tsc.cmd instead of tsc

example:

**Before :** tsc script.ts && node script.js

**After  :** tsc.cmd script.ts && node script.js

Comment: Duplicate answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/63150635/9319588

Answer (score 8):

### Solved

The error "tsc.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system" occurs when the execution policy does not allow running the specific script on Windows.

### To solve this issue you can use any of these three methods:

---

1. Use the `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` command to solve the error.

---

Open your PowerShell as an administrator and set its execution policy with the Set-ExecutionPolicy command.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

If you aren't able to run the command as an administrator, try running it with the **CurrentUser** parameter.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

The `Get-ExecutionPolicy` command should display the execution policy for the current session (RemoteSigned). Use it to confirm if you have changed it.

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

2. Add .cmd to the command

---

By adding .cmd to the command it tells PowerShell to use the cmd version instead.

```
tsc.cmd -v

tsc.cmd --init

tsc.cmd myFile.ts
```

3. You can also try prefixing the `tsc` command with `npx`

---

The `npx` prefix is an npm package runner that can run packages from the npm registry without installing them.

```
npx tsc -v

npx tsc --init

npx tsc myFile.ts
```

Read more from https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-tsc-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-disabled

Answer (score 5):

In VS Code, use `tsc.cmd` instead of `tsc`. For example:

```
tsc.cmd -v
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **Powershell** as default shell then you will get this error on Running:
[as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFzvL.png)

To fix this you have the following options. you can choose any of these to sort out your issue:

1. you  have to enable execution policy by following command in PS(Powershell):

   Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

once it's enabled you can run **tsc** command directly.

- Since Powershell is the default shell terminal, you use following command to run all typescript related commands like :

  **tsc.cmd -v**
- You can change you default shell from **Powershell** to **cmd** by following method in Visual studio code. then using **cmd** shell you can use typescript normally like **tsc -v** instead of using **tsc.cmd -v**

steps to enable **cmd.exe** as default shell for VS Code:

- Press `ctrl+shift+p`
- Press 'terminal: select default profile'
  [as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VPlS.png)
- Select **cmd.exe** as default terminal shell.
  [as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcV8s.png)
- Now in terminal window you will see **cmd.exe**
  [as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoxA2.png)

Comment: Would like to insert your images directly in the text, or do prefer to leave them as links ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your PowerShell as an administrator and set its execution policy with the "get-ExecutionPolicy" command. it will show you restricted.
2. type "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"
3. ask you yes for all type [A]

**Other Option**

4. Type "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned"
5. check tsc --int
6. See below steps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJZQv.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to `File > Settings > Extensions > JSON > Schema` and add this to that JSON:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

Restart and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this. I have solved my problem with doing this:

1. Try this: open terminal/cmd and type: `npm install typescript --save-dev`,
2. compile with: npx tsc or you can do this: `npx tsc --watch`.
   More about that: https://www.typescriptlang.org/download.

Answer (score 0):

"**File Cannot Be Loaded Because Running Scripts Is Disabled on This System In Windows Powershell  FIX.**"
This is observed in latest update in permissions by windows all we need to do is search for Powershell in windows start and run as administartor and runn the followiing commands which is given below.

If you are running into an error saying that your script "cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system" while trying to run a script in Powershell, on Windows 10, you have to change the execution policies first.

**Commands to be entered in power shell:**

1)Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

2)Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

3)Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force

**Note:- u will be prompted to give Y/N after giving the 2nd command,so give as 'Y' and click on enter button**

If PowerShell throws up an error message – File cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system, then you need to enable script running on your Windows 10 computer. The cause of this error comes to the fact that your user account does not have enough permissions to execute that script. This does not mean that you need to have an Administrator level permissions, it also means that you also need to be unrestricted to run these type of PowerShell scripts or cmdlets

Comment: No, this is a workaround, and a dangerous one at that.  This should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio code-> terminal ->open new terminal
Then in right corner of terminal there is an arrow ↓ besides + sign -> select "cmd"
Then you can run
tsc filename.ts command without using
tsc. cmd filename.ts
Then use node filename
Here is your output... taaaa-daaaaa

Answer (score 0):

in VS code it will be solve by adding this code to the `setting.json`.

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  "PowerShell": {
    "source": "PowerShell",
    "icon": "terminal-powershell",
    "args": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
  }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
```

[refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56199111/visual-studio-code-cmd-error-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabl/67420296#67420296)

Answer (score 0):

if you do just this

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

you might be greeted with the error

Set-ExecutionPolicy : Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied. To change the execution policy for
the default (LocalMachine) scope, start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option. To change the execution policy for the current user, run "Set-ExecutionPolicy
-Scope CurrentUser".
At line:1 char:1

- Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
- ```
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
  ```

So, what you have to do is run windows powershell as administrator then type this:

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser

Then set,

ExecutionPolicy: remotesigned

Then say yes to all by typing A and everything will be okay. goodlu

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to install the new open-source powershell if you're on windows https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases

This fixed all our woes, including running scripts being disabled. We also had issues with `git bash` regarding the way paths are handled differently (ex: backslash, forward slash).

It's the simplest and most foolproof solution in my opinion, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Below command works for me. Run in Shell Terminal as **Administrator**:

For more information check the detailed blog by [ms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3)

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Or

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Another solution for the above problem is if you are using VScode or Visual Studio Code.

1. Open the vscode termial by using Ctrl + ` or go on the terminal tab and open it.
2. You can see there are a few tabs and icons.
3. At the top right there would be a symbol 'v' beside the + sign from there select cmd and you are good to go.
4. Example: tsc file.ts (here file is the name of the file you want to compile)
5. As soon as you execute the above command you will get a javascript file, in this case, file.js will be generated...

Hope your issue would be solved...happy coding

Answer (score -1):

Go to `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm` and remove `tsc.ps1`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31759877)