# TypeScript error when this command "tsc index.ts" " shows is not digitally signed"

Tags: javascript, typescript, windows, powershell

## Trying to learn TypeScript but I get an error

`PS C:\Users\jogod\Desktop\TypeScript> tsc index.ts`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wmPu.jpg)

tsc : File C:\Users\jogod\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1 cannot be loaded. The
file C:\Users\jogod\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1 is not digitally signed. You
cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about
running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies
at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- tsc index.ts
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException      
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

I'm expecting that this command `tsc index.ts` will create another file of "index.js"

Comment: When learning anything about computer, especially programming languages, the first lesson is always to actually read and research error messages.  This error message even conveniently gives you a link to everything you need to know and how to fix.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796490/tsc-ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system

Comment: Unfortunately, PowerShell defaults to _preventing_ execution of script files (`*.ps1`) in workstation editions of Windows, necessitating a change in [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) to allow their execution.
See the linked duplicate for details.