# Installing the Vercel CLI in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vercel

I have logged in to Vercel using my Github account.

I run the command npm install -g vercel in Visual Studio Code (in the relevant project directory), it installs successfully but when I run 'vercel' or 'vercel login' it gives me the error:

> *vercel : The term 'vercel' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included,  verify that the path is correct and
> try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - vercel login
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (vercel:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException*
>   ```

Any advice will be appreciated!!
Thanks

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/56199111/266535

Answer (score 4):

Your **PowerShell** doesn't know the path where vercel located. To run vercel scripts you have to manually install or run the **.ps1** script for the Powershell.

Run this script with PowerShell: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\vercel.ps1`

Answer (score 3):

if you are using ubuntu and you used yarn to install vercel just head to your  terminal and run this command  export PATH=$PATH:~/.yarn/bin

Comment: This is not just for ubuntu. Had the same issue + fix for Mac. The same can happen for npm too btw (but than the path is different, of course)

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions didn't work for windows at all.

Here's how I fixed it:

Open CMD in "Administrator" mode.

```
npm cache clear --force

npm install

npm config set cache C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

npm config set prefix C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Now do:

```
npm i -g vercel

vercel --version
```

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just if you still have this problem running `vercel --prod` gave me an error that said "not recognized" `npm vercel --prod` worked thought