# I installed npm live server (js.node) but it dosen't work?

Tags: node.js, npm-live-server

I have installed node.js and then installed npm live server
but when i want to use live server using terminal in vs code by

> live-server

I get:

```
live-server : File C:\Users\**\AppData\Roaming\npm\live-server.ps1 cannot be loaded   
because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ live-server
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

so how can i solve this problem?

Comment: See existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56199111/visual-studio-code-cmd-error-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabl

Answer (score -1):

The answer in the output

```
For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
```

You have to turn on script execution in your Windows.

Comment: i did ,  and i got (in terminal) : 

   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)   

....

Comment: I never used live-server (I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server instead)...
May be this https://github.com/tapio/live-server/issues/190