# How can I fix VS Code error about_Execution_Policies while using Angluar?

Tags: angular, windows, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I have been trying to create app using Angular-cli. But for some reason when I run `ng new myApp`. It gives me this error.

I tried using this to fix it, but it didn't work... Or did I put it to wrong place?
Anyways all help is appreciated!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67420296/18683870

[Screenshot of the problem][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV800.png

The error:

```
ng : File C:\Users\onnia\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more inf ormation, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1
+ ng new myApp
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60284384/5437671

Comment: what do you read at the shown link