# Firebase cannot be loading because running scripts is disabled on this system firebase init is not working

Tags: reactjs

I have installed the firebase hosting tools, when I try to initialize firebase hosting using the terminal from Vscode, I receive the following error. Why is that?

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: Please check this answer, it should solve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56199112/14625859