# Sanity start is not running on my Vs code

Tags: sanity

After project was successfully created in my system.
When I try to run sanity start, it fails and shows “cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled  on this system”
How do I resolve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this is to change the terminal setting of your Vscode to CMD. Here is a post that explains in further detail.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61293119/15581011

Answer (score 0):

You could elevate your powershell by typing this `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser` and then changing the mode to `Unrestricted`